# How to create alerts using CloudWath for Spring Boot metrics?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-micrometer

I have a Spring Boot microservice (Spring Cloud Gateway) deployed on AWS EKS. It sends metrics to CloudWatch, but I can't figure out how to define an alert on an aggregate metric.
This is a sample of the metrics:

[image: Spring Cloud Gateway metrics]

I added a custom tag ("instanceId") which provides the instance identifier of the pod:

```
@Bean
public MeterRegistryCustomizer<CloudWatchMeterRegistry> cloudWatchMetricsCommonTags() {
    return (registry) -> registry.config().commonTags("instanceId", EC2MetadataUtils.getInstanceId());
}
```

This query provides the slowest request:

```
SELECT MAX("spring.cloud.gateway.requests.max") FROM "tas-gpp-gateway"
```

[image: Max graph]

But it seems to be impossible define an alert on it. I found [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55543319/creating-a-cloudwatch-alarm-based-on-a-search-expression), but I can't provide all possible metric dimensions because outcome, httpMethod and instanceId have many different values. In fact, according to the documentation, you should:

- provide a set of metrics
- define a math expression using the metrics
- create an alert based on the math expression

For example:

[image]

But this is not an option, because I can't list all the possible dimensions of the metric **spring.cloud.gateway.requests.max**.